# как сделать замену свободного числа в js?

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть span, внутри которого строка 'Название категории, страница #2', номер страницы меняется по переходам на сайте, как я могу сделать реплейс этой строки, чтобы убирать все, что после запятой, т.е оставить только название категории?

Comment: добавть данные, как хотите заменять (с чего на что). А так думаю вам может помочь методе `String.replace(RegExpr, function(match){ return match })`

Comment: Уточните, в конце всегда ", страница #*"? (вместо звездочки число)